# NPM dependencies error

Tags: angular, npm

I have tried uninstalling, clearing cache and reinstalling latest Angular many times. Still not working. My system configuration is Win10(32).

I checked already based on this peer dependency errors posts but that is not my problem. After installing the required versions of peer dependencies it still asking to install it manually. I dont know how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
------------------------------------------------------


            **C:\Users\vissu\npm\ng -> C:\Users\vissu\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
            npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.**

            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
            npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

            + @angular/cli@1.7.0
            updated 1 package in 88.21

            I am getting above error of Peer Dependencies atfer installing it manually .i already installed the required version of ajv@^6.0.0 please find it below

            C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm ls

            system32@1.0.0 C:\WINDOWS\system32

            +-- ajv@6.0.0

            | +-- fast-deep-equal@1.0.0

            | +-- fast-json-stable-stringify@2.0.0

            | `-- json-schema-traverse@0.3.1

            +-- ajv-keywords@3.1.0

            +-- angular2@2.0.0-beta.21
            +-- es5-shim@4.5.10
            +-- es6-shim@0.35.3
            +-- install-peers@1.0.2
            | `-- executioner@2.0.1
            |   `-- mixly@1.0.0
            |     `-- fulcon@1.0.2
            +-- reflect-metadata@0.1.2
            +-- rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
            `-- zone.js@0.6.26

            Why am not able to install Angular, and i  installed every Peer Dependency. and i am using below versions of node n npm.
           Versions//
            Node: v9.5.0
            NPM: 5.6.0

            And i tried uninstalling , clearing cache and reinstalling latest Angular many times . still not working.my system configuration is Win10(32).
i checked already based on this peer dependency errors posts but that is not my problem , after installing the required versions of peer dependencies it still asking to install it manually i dont know how to do it. please help me.
```

### please find the JSON .

```
{
  "name": "system32",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "install-peers": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.1.0",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.10",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  }
}
```

Comment: It says it installed angular...`updated 1 package`

Comment: no!! installation is not completed . there is a warning that AJV is not installed but still i cant use ng command after itinsalled it manually

Answer (score -1):

try installing it with yarn instead

```
yarn global add  @angular/cli@latest
```

yarn is another package manager just like npm, you can install it from here https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

Comment: with yarn i successfully installed but                                   
C:\Users\vissu>ng -v
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. again the same problem